# How do I get a $something included in an http query

Tags: php, file-get-contents

This is from the API og gatewayapi.com:

```
<?php
// Query args
$query = http_build_query(array(
    'token' => 'my-token',
    'sender' => 'ExampleSMS',
    'message' => 'Hello World',
    'recipients.0.msisdn' => 4512345678,
));
// Send it
$result = file_get_contents('https://gatewayapi.com/rest/mtsms?' . $query);
// Get SMS ids (optional)
print_r(json_decode($result)->ids);
```

But I would like to include $something to the message part, it fail when I do this:

```
    <?php

    $something = "my message";

    // Query args
    $query = http_build_query(array(
        'token' => 'my-token',
        'sender' => 'ExampleSMS',
        'message' => '$something',
        'recipients.0.msisdn' => 4512345678,
    ));
    // Send it
    $result = file_get_contents('https://gatewayapi.com/rest/mtsms?' . $query);
    // Get SMS ids (optional)
    print_r(json_decode($result)->ids);
```

Comment: Write `'message' => $something,` - do not use single quote on php variable $something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `'` from variable. Other wise it will not pass variable and take $something as value

```
    $something = "my message";

    // Query args
    $query = http_build_query(array(
        'token' => 'my-token',
        'sender' => 'ExampleSMS',
        'message' => $something,
        'recipients.0.msisdn' => 4512345678,
    ));
    // Send it
    $result = file_get_contents('https://gatewayapi.com/rest/mtsms?' . $query);
    // Get SMS ids (optional)
    print_r(json_decode($result)->ids);
```

Refer the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php